# Android WebViewClient's ShouldInterceptRequest is never called in MAUI WebView

Tags: android, .net, webview, maui

UPDATE: it's a confirmed bug. Please upvote it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11004) because it doesn't really receive a lot of attention from MS.

---

I need to override the `shouldInterceptRequest` method of `WebViewClient` to [load in-app HTML content](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/load-local-content) following that guide.

Here's the repo with the reproducible code: [GitHub](https://github.com/datvm/DemoMauiWvClient). I took a sample code from [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/967507/how-to-set-custom-webviewclient-on-android-handler.html) as well:

```cs
// ...
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
    handlers.AddHandler<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView, ProblemHandler2>();
});
// ...

internal class ProblemHandler2 : WebViewHandler
{

    protected override Android.Webkit.WebView CreatePlatformView()
    {
        var wv = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Android.App.Application.Context);
        wv.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());

        return wv;
    }

}
```

In the repo, I included 2 custom handlers:

- `ProblemHandler2` is the exact snippet by the MSFT. I realized a problem: Setting MAUI `WebView`'s `Source` property no longer navigates the real Android WebView:

```cs
        WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyHandler", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            var xWv = handler.PlatformView;

            // For ProblemHandler2, this is needed to actually navigate:
            xWv.LoadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
#endif
        });

        this.wv.Source = "https://www.google.com/";
```

- `ProblemHandler1` uses the default result and adds a custom handler. This fixes the navigation problem, **but**, both problem have the same issue:

**`ShouldInterceptRequest` is never called**. It is never called on anything even when I manually click a link to navigate. What am I missing? I am sure the `CustomWebClient` is correctly created and set.

I noticed none of the other callbacks works as well, for example:

```cs
    public override void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        Debug.WriteLine(url);

        base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        Debug.WriteLine(url);

        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    }
```

I also tried using `WebViewHandler.Mapping` but it also does not work:

```cs
        WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyHandler", (handler, _) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());
#endif
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is the case as you said.

And I have created a new issue for this problem, you can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11004.

Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Is there any workaround I can use in the mean time?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, we can only wait patiently for the release of the new version.

Answer (score 5):

I could be wrong but, I think this might have to do with your overridden version of the `CreatePlatform` method,

Can you try what the default WebViewHandler is doing:

```
protected override WebView CreatePlatformView()
{
        var platformView = new MauiWebView(this, Context!)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent)
        };

        platformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        platformView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        platformView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        return platformView;
}
```

Check this URL for the default handlers CreatePlatform setup :

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/c6250a20d73e1992b4a02e6f3c26a1e6cbcbe988/src/Core/src/Handlers/WebView/WebViewHandler.Android.cs

Also don't use Application Context in Handlers, Handlers have their own Context property you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I won't be able to check it until Monday. However in one of my handler, I did use the result from `base.CreatePlatformView` and just change the client with `SetWebViewClient`, so while I will test on Monday, I think it's unlikely.

Comment: I see, Then this could be a bug and we might have to raise it on Maui Git, I could help you with it if needed :)

Comment: Since it's a confirmed bug I will award the bounty to you so it's not wasted :) The bug report is created by the MSFT person

Answer (score 0):

MAUI provides a specific Mapper for this on Android, you can just modify that mapper.

```
#if ANDROID 

public class CustomWebViewClient : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
{
    // Custom implementation of WebViewClient
}

Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.ModifyMapping(nameof(WebViewClient), (handler, view) =>
{
    var webViewHandler = (WebViewHandler)handler;
    webViewHandler.PlatformView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
});
#endif
```